# Count Number of Times the Sale of a Toy is greater than Average for that Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

I have a dataset where in I have to identify if the Sale value of a Toy is greater than the average  in the column and count in how many different sale areas, value is greater than the average.

For Ex: find the average of column `"Sale B"` - 2.5, check in how many rows the value is greater than 2.5 and then perform the same exercise for `"SaleA"` and `"SaleC"` and then add all of it

```
input_data = pd.DataFrame({'Toy': ['A','B','C','D'],
                      'Color': ['Red','Green','Orange','Blue'],
                      'SaleA': [1,2,0,1],
                      'SaleB': [1,3,4,2],
                      'SaleC': [5,2,3,5]})
```

New column `"Count_Sale_Average"` is created, For ex: for toy "A" only at one position the sale was greater than average.

```
output_data = pd.DataFrame({'Toy': ['A','B','C','D'],
                      'Color': ['Red','Green','Orange','Blue'],
                      'SaleA': [1,2,0,1],
                      'SaleB': [1,3,4,2],
                      'SaleC': [5,2,3,5],
                       'Count_Sale_Average':[1,2,1,1]})
```

My code is working and giving the desired output. Any suggestions on other ways of doing it, may be more efficient and in less number of lines.

```
list_var = ['SaleA','SaleB','SaleC']
df = input_data[list_var]

for i in range(0,len(list_var)):
    var = list_var[i]
    mean_var = df[var].mean()
    df[var] = df[var].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > mean_var else 0)
    
df['Count_Sale_Average'] = df[list_var].sum(axis=1)
output_data = pd.concat([input_data, df[['Count_Sale_Average']]], axis=1)
output_data
```

Comment: are you sure the output is correct?

Comment: It was an error while creating the dataset. @mozway - Thank you for highlighting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `filter`, find `mean` and `sum` on axis:

```
filtered = input_data.filter(like='Sale')
input_data['Count_Sale_Average'] = filtered.gt(filtered.mean()).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Toy   Color  SaleA  SaleB  SaleC  Count_Sale_Average
0   A     Red      1      1      5                   1
1   B   Green      2      3      2                   2
2   C  Orange      0      4      3                   1
3   D    Blue      1      2      5                   1
```